# Map symbolization - style file: compute change for the Label?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, symbology, esri-geodatabase, style

Situation:

How to get the attributes/values of a field **COD** in an Attributes Table of a Feature Class (picture attached - attr_table) using another field **COD_SYMB** (which acts as a key-field) in that same attributes table?

In ArcMap, COD_SYMB is the field selected ---> Layer properties for the "*Value Field*" in the Symbology by categories (match to symbols in a style: picture attached - layer_prop). Code values for the symbology are loaded from a Style File created a priori (picture attached - style_file).

In the *Style File* ---> field/column "*Name*" contains the same values of those inserted previously in the field COD_SYMB so they can match.

In the *Layer properties* we have then: the field/column "**Label**" shows the attributes of **COD_SYMB**. And the field/column "**Value**" contains the color codes ---> **COD_SYMB**.
In terms of style symbolization, we need to compute a way (function/method) to replace the Label with COD_SYMB values by the field COD and its values.... In other words, when values/codes of field **COD_SYMB** are read, a method gets the correspondent values/codes in the field **COD** and returns them as Label field (picture attached - layer_prop - attr_tab - style_file relationship representation).

Any help?

I'm working on ArcGIS 10.3.

Note:

Is there a way to convert the Symbology by Style into UNIQUE_VALUES to apply this:

UniqueValuesSymbology—Help | ArcGIS for Desktop ---> desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/uniquevaluessymbology-class.htm
?

Pictures illustrating a minimal working example:

[image: attributes_table]
[image: layer properties + symbolization/style]
[image: style file]
[image: layer_prop - attr_tab - style_file relationship representation]